# Why schema registry internal topic _schemas has only single partition?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

From confluent documentation [here](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/index.html#ak-backend)

> Kafka is used as Schema Registry storage backend. The special Kafka topic `<kafkastore.topic>` (default _schemas), with a single partition, is used as a highly available write ahead log..

_schemas topic is created with single partition. What is the design rational behind this? Having number of partitions more than 1 will definitely improve search for schemas by the consumers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schemas topic **must** be ordered, therefore it has one partition. The producer in the server also only uses the default partitioner.

Since there's only one partition, there is only one consumer, anyway (the master registry server), therefore doesn't need to scale; the HTTP server can handle thousands of requests/second perfectly fine. A reverse proxy can be introduced for high availability, rather than for improving throughput, i.e. load balancing.

The schemas are stored all in memory in ConcurrentHashMap(s) after consuming the topic. The "search" you're referring to, therefore is already an O(1) operation.

External consumers and producers also cache the schemas after using them once in an HTTP request, as part of the (de)serializer classes.

The replication factor of one allows for local development without editing configs. **You should change this**.

Kafka's own internal topics (consumer offsets and transaction topics) default to 1, as well, by the way. And `num.partitions` also defaults to 1 for auto-created topics, but I'd suggest turning off auto topic creation.